# Can the LinkedIn API be used to automate collecting data about people's current job, previous jobs and education?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm doing a machine learning project for my thesis at university. For this I require information about where people are currently working, where they have previously worked and what their education is. I require this data on a large scale, so collecting it by hand is not viable. Therefore, I wondered if it's possible to use the LinkedIn API to collect this kind of data for this purpose? In particular, I would need to collect this data from thousands of profiles for a given company, for about 50 different companies (i.e. on the order of 100,000 profiles). For instance, I would need the employment and educational history of some 2000 Microsoft employees, or 2000 Facebook employees, and so on, all exported into a spreadsheet file.

Can the LinkedIn API be used for this, or is there some other way of achieving this?